# Style ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock and trying to style ActionMode. I can change background and done button using these attributes in my style:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/abs__ic_cab_done_holo_dark</item>
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
```

But I can not figure out how to set the color of the vertical line just next to the done button. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with this code in my theme:

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/action_button_done</item>
```

And the style action_button_done just sets the background drawable:

```
<style name="action_button_done" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__btn_cab_done_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

**Warning**

This should be a simple thing to do. And it was, but for some reason htc decided to put an extra layer on top of the button that makes it impossible to style it. I was just lucky that I tried deploying on my friends samsung galaxy nexus and noticed that it actually worked. I only used htc one x, so don't know if it is the same on other htc devices.